# TextInputLayout hint is not visible in nexus

Tags: android, user-interface, android-xml, nexus-5, nexus6

In Below Mentioned Code i am not able to see the hint text in nexus phone, in other phone it is working fine, and looks according to code.

> ```
>  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>                 android:id="@+id/til"
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
>                 <com.hul.humarashop.CustomFontTextView.EditTextGothamBook
>                     android:id="@+id/editName"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>                     android:background="#00000000"                         
>                     android:hint="Name"
>                     android:padding="10dp"
>                     android:singleLine="true"
>                     android:textColor="#000000"
>                     android:textColorHint="#000000"
>                     android:textSize="15sp"></com.hul.humarashop.CustomFontTextView.EditTextGothamBook>
>
>             </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `app:hint="Name"` on the TextInputLayout, rather than the EditText.

Just to note as well - you might like to know that the TextInputLayout has a [getEditText()](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#getEditText()) method! This means you only have to use one id in the xml, tidying up the code a little.

Comment: No ,now its not coming in any device.

Comment: Woops sorry it's app:hint="Name"!

Comment: There is no parameter "app:hint" in TextInputLayout as well as in EditText